# LWJGL installation not working

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I am trying to install LWJGL 3.0.0b build 9 on Eclipse, and have followed multiple tutorials, but when I try to use the classes it cannot find them.

These images show a program copied from the official tutorial, and the 3 LWJGL folders, then the project properties, configured as instructed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a22u.png

If you can offer help, I would be very appreciative, thanks!

Comment: Slightly off topic: In my older days of Java(I have grown up since then and moved on to better, well built languages), I found Eclipse to be absolute trash. You should be using IntelliJ.

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on your project, select "properties", then select "Java build path", add a reference to your jar there and it should work.

Comment: That is done, there are two imgur images and the second one displays that configuration, but thanks